# How to find if a values exists in ArrayList

Tags: android, sqlite

I have inserted some values in SQLite. Before inserting values I need to check if that values already exists in the database.

That's why I inserted all rows in SQLite database values into an `ArrayList` .

When I click submit button need to check either that object already existed or not.

How can I do this?

```
Cursor cursor = raisePoProductInformationHelper.searchDetails(UserSharedPreferences.getPreferenceString(Constants.USER_NAME, null), sqLiteDatabase);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        String ProductName = cursor.getString(0);
        String Qty = cursor.getString(2);
        SqliteRaisePoDetailsBean sqliteRaisePoDetailsBean = new SqliteRaisePoDetailsBean(ProductName, Qty);
        sqliteRaisePoDetailsBeanArrayList.add(sqliteRaisePoDetailsBean);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    cursor.close();
}

private void submitButtonAction(){
    if(sqliteRaisePoDetailsBeanArrayList.contains("")) {
        System.out.println("yes it's contains");
    } else {
        System.out.println("no it's not contains");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to make `contains` method for your custom object?

Comment: need not contains method especially when i insert my values in Sqlite Db before need to check arrayList having that inserted values or not

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check, use an efficient method for that, like `HashSet`

To check it, you only need to call:

```
HashSet set = new HashSet<String>();
set.contains(yourString);
```

[Android Doc for HashSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashSet.html)

Comment: i am begginer in android

Comment: I don't know how you save your data, but if you know how to use ArrayList HashSet is the same. Check the link and you'll see